# Role required to perform validate action on resource group

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-resource-group

I am trying to run the following powershell command on an Azure API Management resource group:

```
Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName api-dev-81575006 -TemplateFile .\api-dev.json -TemplateParameterFile .\api-dev.parameters-TEST.json
```

However I get the following error:

```
Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : The client 'xx.xx@blabla.com' with object id '89e711a3-374d-4594-8aba-e0108edf2a87' does not have authorization to perform action 
'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action' over scope
```

I looked at my role in the resource group and I have contributor role. Shouldn't this be sufficient for me to run validate commands on resource groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yeah, thats sufficient, so you've got few options here:

1. you dont know who you actually are. i.e. powershell is authenticated under a different user. (`Get-AzContext` will show you this information)
2. you are deploying to the wrong resource group (so not the one you checked permissions)
3. you are deploying to the wrong subscription (`Get-AzContext` will show you this information; you can switch subscription with `Select-AzSubscription`)

also, worth noting, that i'm 99% sure that cmdlet doesnt do what you think it does ;)

Comment: In what way doesn't it do what I think it does? It should validate an arm template deployment with  the parameter files. Or have I misstaken something?

Comment: not necessary, and even if that cmdlet returns OK it doesnt mean that the template will actually work (in small\easy templates it most likely will). also, when you run `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` it does run that validation before actually running the template. so its not really usefull

Comment: That is true, am aware of that, but right now we are just trying to evaluate various validation steps for a complete pipeline. Normally we deploy via Azure devops and use the validate step there. This is just for evaluation purpose.

Comment: Wrong subscription. Thanks for the help.